# Sharing tasks among parallel independent jobs

Tags: design, architecture, distributed-computing, parallelism, distributed-system

I am getting files on HDFS and I have a legacy java app which checks for new files every 15 mins, does some transformations and write them to some remote server.

Now, I am facing scaling issue with this APP. I don't want to rewrite this complex app, I am thinking about adding some files distribution mechanism and running multiple instances of this app in parallel.

One way of doing so is write file paths in some queue and all these parallel instances will listen to this queue. This will require very few changes and looks good solution to me but this will require a new light weight process which will check for new files on HDFS and write their names in queue.

Is there any good way by which I can avoid this new process?

I am thinking about following options:

- All parallel instances will check for files in input directory and then try to acquire lock for current file in Database or Redis.
- All parallel instances vote and elect leader for each file which will process them.

Comment: Do you believe adding a voting system for the processes is simpler than a process pushing into the queue? If yes, then go for it. But I doubt that is the case. I recommend following the simplest approach to avoid complexity and effort trying to find out what went wrong.